# Problem with files size

Tags: files-and-directories, memory

I need to work with long time series, but I notice that this generates huge files that Mathematica doesn't handle well at all: even opening/saving one of this files is difficult, and the kernel quits often while doing simple tasks.

I attach an example: the  TemporalData object generated and stored in 'data' is 150 MB (and it's not even a half of what I need). Graphics are huge: each one of the Manipulate objects are ~ 150 MB, and they include no more than 300 stills. The total size of this notebook, once compiled, 650 MB circa, more or less a low quality AVI of a standard movie of one hour and a half.

Is this standard for Mathematica? Should I send the output to external files and in this case which is the right way to do this, without losing the nice interactive features of the program?

Thanks

```
force[x_] := (a x - b x^3)
drive[t_] := \[ScriptCapitalA] Sin[2 π (ω t + α)]


ClearAll[paramrule, forceRule]
forceRule = {ϵ -> 0.003, a -> 1, 
b -> 1, \[ScriptCapitalA] -> 0.35, ω -> ϵ/(
2 π), α -> 0}; paramrule = 
Join[forceRule, {σ -> 0.2, Subscript[x, 0] -> -1.5, 
Subscript[T, range] -> {0., 15000, 0.1}}]
{ϵ -> 0.003, a -> 1, 
b -> 1, \[ScriptCapitalA] -> 0.35, ω -> ϵ/(
2 π), α -> 0, σ -> 0.2, Subscript[x, 0] -> -1.5, 
Subscript[T, range] -> {0., 15000, 0.1}}

proc := ItoProcess[{force[x] + drive[t], σ}, {x, Subscript[x, 
0]}, t] //. paramrule

data = RandomFunction[proc, Subscript[T, range] , 100] //. paramrule

Histogram[data["SliceData", 10000], Automatic, "PDF"]

Manipulate[
Histogram[data["SliceData", t], {-2, 2, 0.1}, "PDF"], {t, 10000, 
12000, 100}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]
Manipulate[
Histogram[data["SliceData", t], {-2, 2, 0.1}, "PDF"], {t, 12000, 
15000, 10}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]
Manipulate[
 Histogram[data["SliceData", t], {-2, 2, 0.1}, "PDF"], {t, 12000, 
  15000, 10}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```